# amazon s3 image downloading on Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I'm noticing a really weird occurrence on Android. I have a bucket which has a number of images that I need to display on my iPhone and Android apps. On the iPhone, everything works fine as I use `SDWebImage` to download, cache, and show the image. On the Android app i'm using `Shutterbug`.

When I download the image on Android using the below link everything works fine:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/{{bucket name}}/image.png

However, when I use the below link, I get errors:

https://{{bucket name}}.s3.amazonaws.com/image.png

The error I get is below:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: https://{{bucket name}}.s3.amazonaws.com/image.png
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:279)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
at com.applidium.shutterbug.downloader.ShutterbugDownloader$1.doInBackground(ShutterbugDownloader.java:65)
at com.applidium.shutterbug.downloader.ShutterbugDownloader$1.doInBackground(ShutterbugDownloader.java:52)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Is there any reason why i'm getting this when changing the URL? I would ideally prefer the second one because it will allow for Google's robot.txt to be read.

Comment: Have you made the images public??

Comment: Yes, of course. Thats why the first link works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names

Turns out that my bucket had underscores in it's name (_). This goes against the standards. In iOS even with non-standard characters these URL's were working, but in Android it rejects it. Best to make sure not to use non-standard characters for s3 bucket names.

If you do, use the first link. In that case the dns lookup doesn't have non-standard characters in it (https://s3.amazonaws.com/...)